# Where does the term blob come from in the context of git?

Tags: git, blob

Follow-up: Does it have anything to do with Binary Large OBjects from Database Management Systems?

Comment: Possibly, although throughout the computer world "blob" is often used to refer to any opaque collection of bytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`git man page`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) seems to be surprisingly bereft of an official definition, other than this (emphasis mine):

> The **object database** contains objects of three main types: **blobs, which hold file data**; trees, which point to blobs and other trees to build up directory hierarchies; and commits, which each reference a single tree and some number of parent commits.

The repeated use of the term "object database" across git documentation suggests a borrowing of "blob" specifically from DBMSs.

In its article on [Binary large objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_large_object) Wikipedia defines the term as "a collection of binary data stored as a single entity in a database management system", further offering the following:

> Blobs were originally just amorphous chunks of data invented by Jim Starkey at DEC, who describes them as "the thing that ate Cincinnati, Cleveland, or whatever" from "the 1958 Steve McQueen movie", referring to The Blob. Later, Terry McKiever, a marketing person for Apollo, felt that it needed to be an acronym and invented the backronym Basic Large Object. Then Informix invented an alternative backronym, Binary Large Object.

So, though it's not a definitive answer, the term "blob" has a conventional and well-defined usage across computer science as an opaque string of binary data, and git adheres to that definition without further specifying it.